# std::map seems to find elements which are not there

Tags: c++, fibonacci

So I've tried to create a simple program to calculate n-th fibonacci number mod `10^9+7` using the [doubling formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975741/applying-fibonacci-fast-doubling-identities) with `F[0]=0` and `F[1]=1`. and the program seems to work on my computer with compilers VS2010 and CodeBlocks with MinGW however testing my program on ideone returns 0 for every input. It seems that after the first iteration F.find(n) actually finds elements which shouldn't exist. Here's my code (in VS2010 I just changed the includes).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
std::map<unsigned long long,unsigned long long> F;
unsigned long long fib(unsigned long long n)
{
    if(n==-1) return 0; // Shifting index by 1
    if(n==0) return 1;
    if(n==1) return 1;
    if(F.find(n) != F.end()) return F[n]; // This seems to be the problem,
    else
    {
        if(n%2==0) //
        {
            F[n/2-1] = fib(n/2-1)%1000000007;
            F[n/2] = fib(n/2)%1000000007;
            return F[n] = (F[n/2-1]*F[n/2-1]+F[n/2]*F[n/2])%1000000007;
        }
        else
        {
            F[n/2] = fib(n/2)%1000000007;
            F[n/2+1] = fib(n/2+1)%1000000007;
            return F[n] = (F[n/2]*(2*F[n/2+1]-F[n/2]))%1000000007;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    unsigned long long int broj; 
    cin >> broj; // input the number
    cout << fib(broj-1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, but `F.find(n)` will already find the element. It seems wasteful to search for it again with `F[n]` when you've just obtained a perfectly good iterator to what you are looking for.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `if(n==-1) return 0;` is suspicious where `n` is `unsigned`.

Comment: And especially do not compound the problem with [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) . Including the entire standard library AND pulling it all into the global namespace is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: I do get all of that this is for educational purposes only to make the code prettier in general when really coding I never use #include <bits/stdc++.h> and using namespace std; , the code can be made more efficient but it'll be less readable.

Comment: Why don't you use an unordered_map here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have issue with expressions like this:

```
F[n/2-1] = fib(n/2-1)%1000000007;
```

as order of evaluation of `operator[]` on `std::map` is not defined it may call it before `fib(n/2-1)` and create an empty element there. You should store cached value in function where you calculate it.

Also calling `std::map::operator[]` with the same `key` as you used with `std::map::find` is wasteful.

Possible fix:

```
   auto p = F.emplace( n, 0 );
   if( p.second ) { 
       // element was not there
       // calculate and store at p.first->second
   }
   return p.first->second;
```

Comment: *You should store cached value in function where you calculate it.* or use `F.insert(std::make_pair(n/2-1, fib(n/2-1)%1000000007));`

Comment: @RSahu that would lead to double lookup

Comment: I didn't think so but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @RSahu one lookup this insert, another one inside `fib(n/2-1)` how second one can be avoided?

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible fix is to add two temp variables lets say
`unsigned long long a,b;` and change the lines

```
F[n/2-1] = fib(n/2-1)%1000000007;
F[n/2] = fib(n/2)%1000000007;
```

To

```
a = fib(n/2-1)%1000000007;
b = fib(n/2)%1000000007;
F[n/2-1] = a;
F[n/2] = b;
```

This way it doesn't matter whether map creates the element then assign value. It also can optimize the following line

```
return F[n] = (F[n/2-1]*F[n/2-1]+F[n/2]*F[n/2])%1000000007;
```

To avoid searching for F[n/2-1] and F[n/2] into

```
return F[n] = (a*a+b*b)%1000000007;
```